# Как скопировать всех детей ноды и вставить её в конец родителя?

Tags: javascript, frontend, dom

Пытаюсь взять всех детей элемента, в моём примере это 4 div с классом inside, вложенный в div с классом new-block. Задача чтобы по клику на зелёный див все 4 элемента копировались и подставлялись в конец родительского блока new-block.
Пробовал найти все элементы по классу с помощью querySelectorAll и добавить их использую appenchild, но тогда выходит ошибка:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>"
```

Далее попробовал найти детей родителя и добавить их тем же методом и получил ошибку снова.
Если создать новую ноду и добавить её, то получается что добавляется весь узел, а не только дети.
Та же ошибка выходит если добавить через insertBefore.
При добавлении через insertAdjacentHTML в блок добавляется вот такая запись, вместо цветных прямоугольников [object HTMLCollection]

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно добавить в конец new-block всех его детей по клику, чтобы они были продолжением этого списка. Нужно для создания галереи, пока тренируюсь на прямоугольниках. Хочу чтобы при клике по первому квадрату все 4 элемента копировались и подставлялись в конец родителя.

```js
let newBlock = document.querySelector('.new-block');
// По клику на квадрат все четыре div-а должны добавляться в конец родителя new-block
let click = document.querySelector('.click');

click.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let inside = document.querySelectorAll('.inside');
  for (let ins of inside) {
    newBlock.appendChild(ins[1]);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="new-block">
  <img src="Slide-1.jpg" class="inside click" width="200px" height="auto" alt="">
  <img src="Slide-2.jpg" class="inside" width="200px" height="auto" alt="">
  <img src="Slide-3.png" class="inside" width="200px" height="auto" alt="">
  <img src="Slide-4.jpg" class="inside" width="200px" height="auto" alt="">
  <div class="new-block">
    <div class="inside click"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Песочница https://codepen.io/Alius999/pen/qBVqbYq

Состояние кода ДО клика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После клика должно быть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Есть простое решение. Вы ведь знаете, с каким классом, и какого типа будут элементы? В вашем случае это `<div class="inside"></div>`. Значит самый быстрый вариант, будет такой:

```js
let newBlockChildrens = document.querySelectorAll('.inside');
let newBlock = document.querySelector('.new-block');
let click = document.querySelector('.click');

click.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
for(let i=0; i < newBlockChildrens.length; i++){
newBlock.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newBlockChildrens[i].outerHTML)
}})
```

```css
.click{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
    <div class="new-block"> Блок 1
        <div class="inside click">123</div>
        <div class="inside">456</div>
        <div class="inside">789</div>
        <div class="inside">012</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас! 
Также решил задачу следующим кодом:

click.addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (let ins of inside) {
           let cloneIns = ins.cloneNode(true);
           inside.forEach(function(){
                 newBlock.appendChild(cloneIns);
          })
      }
})

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена. Добавил всех детей родителю в конец с помощью перебора каждого элемента и добавления каждого из них методом forEach:

```
click.addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (let ins of inside) {
           let cloneIns = ins.cloneNode(true);
           inside.forEach(function(){
                 newBlock.appendChild(cloneIns);
          })
      }
})
```